# What is Compiler Generated constructor for abstract class no data members

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class, language-lawyer, static-analysis

I'm running a static analysis tool and getting an error because an abstract class, with no data members, has no constructors.

Given an abstract class with no data members:

```
class My_Interface
{
  public:
    virtual void interface_function(void) = 0;
};
```

1. Are any constructors generated by the compiler?
2. If a constructor is generated, what would it's content be?
3. If a constructor is generated, would it be eliminated by an
   optimization level?

The rule documentation in the static analysis says:
*If you do not write at least one constructor in a class, the compiler will
write a public constructor for you by default. This rule detects if you
do not declare at least one constructor.*

The rule documentation references Scott Meyers, "Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve your Programs and Design", third edition.

My understanding is that the compiler will not generate constructors for the above case.

**Edit 1:**
This is not a duplicate of many constructor questions because:

1. This one has no data members.
2. This is not asking if a constructor is necessary, but what happens
   when a constructor is not provided.
3. This is C++ language.

Comment: @DieterLücking: The destructor is not virtual, why should it appear in the vtable? Besides, the vtable should have one entry for `interface_function`

Comment: @DieterLücking: Would the "optimizing away" occur at the "no optimization" (or Debug) setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler at least theoretically synthesizes a constructor even in this case. Even though you can't create an instance of this class, the constructor will be invoked in the process of creating a derived class (that overrides `interface_function`, so it can be instantiated).

Given that this is basically a pure interface class, the constructor probably won't do anything, so most compilers will probably optimize it out (quite possibly even when you don't tell it to optimize the code).

Comment: So to eliminate generation of the constructor, should I use the idiom of declaring private constructors and destructors?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: if you declare the constructor/destructor private, the compiler *shouldn't* allow you to instantiate objects of a derived class, unless you declare it a friend to give it access to those private members. In many cases, however, this is purely theoretical--by default, many compilers don't enforce access restrictions on elided members.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: What exactly are those cases? Which compiler would not generate a diagnostic for `class Base { private: Base() {} }; class Derived : public Base {}; int main() { Derived d; }`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I probably worded things poorly. I'm not sure any compiler has ever let that specific case by, but at least some older compilers have been lax about vaguely similar restrictions. I wasn't trying to say: "your compiler will probably allow this even though it's not legal" nearly as much as: "avoid this, even if your compiler doesn't stop you from doing it."

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Are any constructors generated by the compiler?

Yes. Several. First, from [class.ctor]:

> A *default* constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that either has no parameters or else each
>   parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument. If there is no user-declared constructor
>   for class X, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).
>   An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class. A defaulted default
>   constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:

Several bullet points follow, none of which apply. So we have the equivalent of:

```
My_Interface() = default;
```

Then, from [class.copy]:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4).

So we have:

```
My_Interface(const My_Interface&) = default;
```

Also:

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly
>   declared as defaulted if and only if
>   (9.1) — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   (9.2) — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   (9.3) — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>   (9.4) — X does not have a user-declared destructor.

So we also have:

```
My_Interface(My_Interface&& ) = default;
```

> 2. If a constructor is generated, what would it's content be?

All three are generated, all three are `= default;`

> 3. If a constructor is generated, would it be eliminated by an optimization level?

None of the three constructors are *trivial* because `My_Interface` has a virtual function. As such, at the very least, the vtable will need to be initialized/copied. So *something* will have to happen, even if there aren't any members to initialize/copy/move.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Are any constructors generated by the compiler?

Answer: Yes. From the C++11 Standard:

> **12.1 Constructors**
>
> 5 A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If
>   there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared default constructor is an `inline public` member of its class.

I don't see anything in the standard that answers the other two questions. However, in your case, since there is a `virtual` member function, the default constructor must, at least, set the virtual table of the object.

Comment: 1) Is this still valid for versions prior to C++11?  2) My understanding is a virtual table is not required.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Virtual tables are an implementation concept, not a language concept. The standard does not mention them.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I don't have access to the C++03 standards. I am going to guess that the answer to your question is "yes". It make sense to me that the compiler generate a default constructor. A virtual table is definitely required. How can dynamic dispatch be accomplished without that?